# Restrict user to a single workspace in bitbucket

Tags: user-controls, bitbucket, user-management, bitbucket-cloud

I am working on bitbucket cloud but having some challenges with managing users. There are certain people in the team who will be working on a workspace in bitbucket (cloud) version. I would want to restrict users only to a 1 workspace in Bitbucket. However, I am not seeing any control today to restrict users to a single workspace.

Is there any way to restrict the users on bitbucket cloud on a single workspace (user should not be able to create or check-in code in any other repository / workspace)?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, may very on your instance set up.
In your case it should be a new local group with a specific access. Then simply add users to this group

You can find additional details in atlassian documentation:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/grant-access-to-a-workspace/